# factory short sticks length - probabilty question

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, variance, means

> A company manufactures poles. the length of a pole is a random
>   variable **X**, with mean **$\mu_X$** and probability density function
>   ***f*(x)**.
>
> Poles are cut to obtain an exact length **L**. If the initial length
>   of the pole is less than L, the entire pole is lost. If it is greater
>   than **L**, the pole will be cut down to **L**, and the section left
>   over is lost. We are interested in the random variable **Y**, defined
>   as the length of each piece lost.

the first part of the question was to:

1) Express **E(Y)** as a function of ***f*(x)** and **$\mu_X$**. which I did as followed:

E(Y) = $\int$g(x)*f(x)* = $\int_0^L$x*f(x)* +  $\int_L^\infty$(x-L)*f(x)*

but I think I may done it wrong because of I didn't really used **$\mu_X$**
and also because of the next part that I don't know how to answer and probably relays on the previous one:

2)Suppose that **X** follows a normal distribution with mean **$\mu_X$** and variance **$σ_X^2$**. Show that there exists a value $μ$ of $μ_X$ that minimizes $μ_Y$.

am I missing something in the first part? and what is the logic to answer the second part?

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the pole length to be distributed normally, because normal distributions can take negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct (and indeed you do not need $\mu_X$), but can be written in another way:
$$\int_0^L x f(x) \, dx + \int_L^\infty (x-L) f(x) \, dx
= \int_0^L x f(x) \, dx - L \int_L^\infty f(x) \, dx = \mu_X - L\int_L^\infty f(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: thanks. that was very helpful

Comment: @iTSmE Please accept this answer. Thanks.